# Python 3 Class Inheritance Understanding

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to understand class inheritance by paraphrasing someone else's code that looks like this. In my understanding of inheritance by instantiating the View class I have access to all the methods in the writable class. Which seems to be true.

When I setFolder from writable class I know self.outputFolder has a value because in my View class I can call returnFolderView and get the value from self.outputFolder.

However when I return self.path in the function returnPath, I instead get the else condition in the View init function. What I don't understand is why this is happening.

What I would expect is self.outputFolder + self.fileName etc. i.e. the if condition to be true.

Is this an order of operations thing? Any help very much appreciated.

```
OUTPUT_DIR = ''
class writeable():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.fileName = 'writeFile'
        self.outputFolder = kwargs.get('output_dir',OUTPUT_DIR)
        if self.outputFolder:
            self.path = self.outputFolder  + self.fileName if self.outputFolder.endswith('/') else self.outputFolder  + '/' +  self.fileName
        else:
            self.path = self.fileName

        # super(writeable, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def setFolder(self,folder):
        self.outputFolder = folder
        return self

    def returnFolder(self):
        return self.outputFolder


class View(writeable):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(View, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fileName = 'viewFile'
        if self.outputFolder:
            self.path = self.outputFolder  + self.fileName if self.outputFolder.endswith('/') else self.outputFolder  + '/' +  self.fileName
        else:
            self.path = self.fileName

    def returnFolderView(self):
        if self.outputFolder:
            return self.outputFolder
        else:
            print('Failure')

    def returnPath(self):
        return self.path

a = View()
a.setFolder('freddie')
print(a.returnFolderView())
print(a.returnPath())
```

Comment: During `View.__init__()`, `self.outputFolder` has a value of None.  Changing it later via `.setFolder()` does not retroactively change the results that were computed using the original value - you'd need to explicitly update `self.path` in `.setFolder()` if you wanted that behavior.

Comment: @jasonharper thank you very much, was able to fix my problems using your description. @Pynchia not sure what you mean by `useless getters` would love to know more.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @jasonharper comments above updating the setFolder method to update self.path gave the desired behavior.

```
OUTPUT_DIR = ''
class writeable():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.fileName = 'writeFile'
        self.outputFolder = kwargs.get('output_dir',OUTPUT_DIR)
        if self.outputFolder:
            self.path = self.outputFolder  + self.fileName if self.outputFolder.endswith('/') else self.outputFolder  + '/' +  self.fileName
        else:
            self.path = self.fileName

    def setFolder(self,folder):
        self.outputFolder = folder
        ## Added this line to update self.path in the init function
        self.path = self.outputFolder + self.fileName
        return self

    def returnFolder(self):
        return self.outputFolder


class View(writeable):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(View, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fileName = 'viewFile'
        if self.outputFolder:
            self.path = self.outputFolder  + self.fileName if self.outputFolder.endswith('/') else self.outputFolder  + '/' +  self.fileName
        else:
            self.path = self.fileName

    def returnFolderView(self):
        if self.outputFolder:
            return self.outputFolder
        else:
            print('Failure')

    def returnPath(self):
        return self.path

a = View()
a.setFolder('freddie')
print(a.returnFolderView())
print(a.returnPath())
```